# How to pass the current Session object to a method in a C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a class in the App_Code folder of a VS project. I want to write a method that will accept as a parameter the current Session object from a web form. This code does not build:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(System.Web.HttpContext h)
    {
        String s = (String)h.Current.Session["Favorite Flavor"];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Who calls `Foo` and populates `h`? It is likely that `h` already contains what you need.

Comment: foo is called from a web form event handler like Page_Load. I want to pass Session to foo.

Comment: If `h` is an instance, you don't need to call `current`, just get `h.Session`.

Comment: Why not simply passing the value instead of the whole HttpContext? Moreover, you can access the `HttpContext.Current` without passing it through the method params. Simply type `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Something"]`